# how to get owner of token account

Tags: python, spl, solana-py, spl-associated-token-account

I'm using solana-py and trying to get the owner of an associated token account. I have gotten the associated account address like this:

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey
from solana.rpc.api import Client
solana_client = Client("https://solana-api.projectserum.com")

hash = "xxxxxxxxxx"
largest_acc = solana_client.get_token_largest_accounts(PublicKey(hash))
associated_acc = largest_acc["result"]["value"][0]["address"]
```

How do I get the owner's Solana address? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `largestAccountInfo.value.data.parsed.info.owner` sorry it's not in py, but TS example:

```
const tokenMint = "9ARngHhVaCtH5JFieRdSS5Y8cdZk2TMF4tfGSWFB9iSK";
const largestAccounts = await connection.getTokenLargestAccounts(
  new PublicKey(tokenMint)
);
const largestAccountInfo = await connection.getParsedAccountInfo(
  largestAccounts.value[0].address
);
console.log(largestAccountInfo.value.data.parsed.info.owner);
```

[source](https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-the-owner-of-an-nft)

Comment: I tried this before, but in the response I get `{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'result': {'context': {'apiVersion': '1.10.32', 'slot': 146290374}, 'value': {'data':['pvdOR+GRuzgZXU6mpbJjYQY6qcN8DhqimB66AcZFo8vBRbF/lOk+pCmNec7o8ZDnZOln723JvDEMwMAXIAhbowEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'base64'], 'executable': False, 'lamports': 2039280, 'owner': 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA', 'rentEpoch': 337}}, 'id': 2}` which doesn't contain the owner address in it.

Comment: In python I used `largest_info = solana_client.get_account_info(assoc_acc)`

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the other answers on this question to work, however, I was able to get the owner with the public solscan api:

```
request = requests.get(f"https://public-api.solscan.io/token/holders?tokenAddress={hash}&limit=1&offset=0")
request = request.json()
owner = request["data"][0]["owner"]
```